# Why is IConfiguration null when integration testing my Azure Functions?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

The current version of the [Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions/) package exposes an additional property that allows you easy access to the `IConfiguration` provided to the function. Previously this required manually building a service provider, which was obviously problematic.

Using that package my `FunctionsStartup.cs` looks like this:

```
public override void Configure(IFunctionsHostBuilder builder)
{
    base.Configure(builder);

    var config = builder.GetContext().Configuration; // new in v1.1.0 of Microsoft.Azure.Functions.Extensions
    var mySetting = config["MySetting"];

    int.Parse(mySetting, out var mySetting);

    // ... use mySetting...
}
```

In order to test my HTTP-triggered functions I've used [this article](https://saebamini.com/integration-testing-in-azure-functions-with-dependency-injection/) as a base, which details how to manually build and start a host to execute my function as if it was running in Azure, similar to how `TestServer` works in ASP.NET Core:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebJobs(new FunctionsStartup().Configure)
    .Build();

var functionsInstance = ActivatorUtilities.CreateInstance<MyFunctions>(host.Services);
```

I can then execute the function methods defined on `MyFunctions` to test their responses:

```
var request = new DefaultHttpRequest(new DefaultHttpContext());

var response = (OkObjectResult)functionsInstance.HttpTriggerMethod(request);

... assert that response is valid
```

The problem is that when I run my tests, `builder.GetContext().Configuration` is returning `null` in `FunctionsStartup.Configure`, which of course causes those tests to fail. How can I work around this?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The article I linked to hasn't been updated to take into account the existence of `builder.GetContext().Configuration`, but you can make this work for testing purposes with a little tweaking. Instead of using:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebJobs(new FunctionsStartup().Configure)
    .Build();
```

you need to explicitly copy the host's settings into a new `WebJobsBuilderContext` that you then pass to your function's startup:

```
var host = new HostBuilder()
    .ConfigureWebJobs((context, builder) => new FunctionsStartup().Configure(new WebJobsBuilderContext
    {
        ApplicationRootPath = context.HostingEnvironment.ContentRootPath,
        Configuration = context.Configuration,
        EnvironmentName = context.HostingEnvironment.EnvironmentName,
    }, builder))
    .Build();
```

I'm not sure if this is the completely *correct* way to achieve this, but it has worked well for me.

Comment: This does not work with User Secrets.  Any hints on making it work with that?

Comment: @codewise This does work with user secrets but you need to also use the`ConfigureAppConfiguration` method on the hostbuilder.

```csharp
new HostBuilder()
.ConfigureAppConfiguration((hostingContext, config) =>
{
    config.AddUserSecrets<Program>();
})
.Build();
```